# How to get the next tweet in the sequence?

Tags: python, api, twitter, tweepy

I'm making a Python program that interacts with the Twitter API, but I'm not sure how to get the next Tweet in the loop. What's happening is that only the first Tweet in each loop is being called. I need, in each loop, to always call the next Tweet and then interact with them all.

My code:

```
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumerkey, consumerkey_secret)
auth.set_access_token(acesstoken, acesstoken_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True)

r = tweepy.Cursor(api.search_tweets, lista_frases).items(razao_responder)
c = tweepy.Cursor(api.search_tweets, lista_frases_curtir).items(razao_curtir)

for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search_tweets, lista_frases).items(razao_responder):
   while True:
       try:
           if int(tweet.created_at.strftime('%d%m%Y')) >= date_int:
               time.sleep(random.randint(time_init, time_final))
               print('\nTweet respondido de ' + tweet.user.screen_name + '\nTweet ID: ' +    str(tweet.id) +
               '\nTweet date: ' + str(tweet.created_at.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')))
               api.update_status(lista_respostas[0][1:], in_reply_to_status_id=tweet.id)
       except tweepy.Forbidden as e:
           print(e)
       except StopIteration:
           print('No more tweets')
           break
```

The code is working as expected. The only problem is that it doesn't give me the next Tweet found, always interacting with the same Tweet in each loop.

Answer (score 0):

This is because of your `while True`, which infinitely loops with the first `tweet` from `Cursor`.

Comment: So where i put this loop for the logic works? The application must run indefinitely

Comment: Doing what? There's not an infinite number of Tweets to iterate through.